# use external libs in Yii 1

Tags: yii, namespaces, google-api-php-client

I have google lib - https://github.com/rapidwebltd/php-google-contacts-v3-api
and i need to implement it in YII framework

How, for example implement this code in YII:

```
require_once '../../../vendor/autoload.php';

use rapidweb\googlecontacts\helpers\GoogleHelper;

$client = GoogleHelper::getClient();

$authUrl = GoogleHelper::getAuthUrl($client);
```

How to use namespaces in my case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use the composer autoloader, you have to unregister the Yii one first.

Example:

```
spl_autoload_unregister(array('YiiBase','autoload'));
require '../../../vendor/autoload.php';
spl_autoload_register(array('YiiBase','autoload'));

$client = rapidweb\googlecontacts\helpers\GoogleHelper::getClient();
$authUrl = rapidweb\googlecontacts\helpers\GoogleHelper::getAuthUrl($client);
```